# How to delete xml element using qt

Tags: qt

I have xml file like this

```
<Plan>
 <car id="1">491,142;492,138;</car>
 <car id="10073">498,141;489,145;</car>
 <car id="1">483,143;477,145;</car>
 <car id="10075">487,142;490,137;</car>
 <car id="10076">483,137;488,136;</car>
 <car id="10077">484,146;480,144;</car>
 <car id="1">480,147;498,142;</car>
 <car id="10079">488,143;487,147;</car>
 <car id="1">498,141;487,142;</car>
 <car id="10081">487,143;481,144;</car>
 <car id="1">495,137;485,137;</car>
 <car id="10083">486,142;484,140;</car>
 <car id="10084">478,147;479,142;</car>
 <car id="1">493,139;489,139;</car>
 <car id="10087">498,140;490,136;</car>
 <car id="10088">479,145;484,142;</car>
</Plan>
```

how can i delete car element of id "1" using qt library?

Comment: I see neither an xml file nor an id 1. edit : the devil was in the details :)

Comment: @UmNyobe - It was badly formatted and is fixed now.

Comment: next reviewers : probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753782/edit-value-of-a-qdomelement

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
QDomDocument doc;
QFile file("/tmp/1.xml");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
doc.setContent(&file);
QDomElement plan = doc.documentElement();
QDomNodeList cars = plan.childNodes();
for(int i = 0; i < cars.count(); i++) {
  QDomNode node = cars.at(i);
  if (node.isElement() && node.toElement().attribute("id") == "1") {
    plan.removeChild(node);
  }
}
qDebug() << doc.toString();
```